# Python - Future and Previous Calendar Quarter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a requirement where I need do some calculation on result set getting in JSON format (sample below).

```
  {
  "level1": {
    "finalresult": [
      {
        "Amount": "12",
        "Month": "04",
        "Year": "2018",
        "Quarter": "2"
      },
      {
        "Amount": "13",
        "Month": "08",
        "Year": "2018",
        "Quarter": "3"
      },
      {
        "Amount": "13",
        "Month": "07",
        "Year": "2017",
        "Quarter": "3"
      },
      {
        "Amount": "124",
        "Month": "12",
        "Year": "2018",
        "Quarter": "4"
      },
      {
        "Amount": "153",
        "Month": "07",
        "Year": "2018",
        "Quarter": "3"
      }
```

How can I start writing a function to find out sum of amount for following -

**1. Next 3 quarters (from current month)**

**2. Last 2 quarters (from current month)**

How do I proceed ahead from here -

```
response=requests.get("json url")
jsondata=response['level1']['finalresult']

now = datetime.datetime.now()

current_year = now.year

total_sum_last2qrtrs=[]
total_sum_next3qrtrs=[]

for result in jsondata:
```

Comment: What would be example output (total sum) for each of those function calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
current_quarter = ((now.month-1)//3)+1

def total_sum_next3qrtrs():
    year_next_3_quarters = []
    next_3_quarters = [(i%4+1) for i in range(current_quarter, current_quarter+3)]

    amounts = []

    for q in next_3_quarters:
        if q < current_quarter:
            year_next_3_quarters.append({'Year':current_year+1, 'Quarter': q})
        else:
            year_next_3_quarters.append({'Year':current_year, 'Quarter': q})

    for nq in year_next_3_quarters:
        for q in jsondata:
            if nq['Year'] == int(q['Year']) and nq['Quarter'] == int(q['Quarter']):
                amounts.append(int(q['Amount']))
    return sum(amounts)

def total_sum_last2qrtrs():
    year_last_2_quarters = []
    last_2_quarters = [(i%4+1) for i in range(current_quarter-3, current_quarter-1)]

    amounts = []

    for q in last_2_quarters:
        if q < current_quarter:
            year_last_2_quarters.append({'Year':current_year, 'Quarter': q})
        else:
            year_last_2_quarters.append({'Year':current_year-1, 'Quarter': q})

    for nq in year_last_2_quarters:
        for q in jsondata:
            if nq['Year'] == int(q['Year']) and nq['Quarter'] == int(q['Quarter']):
                amounts.append(int(q['Amount']))
    return sum(amounts)

current_quarter = ((now.month-1)//3)+1

print total_sum_next3qrtrs()
print total_sum_last2qrtrs()
```

output:

```
290 # 153 + 124 + 13
0   # None that meet the criteria
```

Of course it may need improvements if the results are not as desired, but it seems to provide correct outputs based on current data.

Comment: Worked perfectly :)

Comment: it gives me this result if make modification to get data for next four quarters - [{'Quarter': 3, 'Year1': 2018}, {'Quarter': 4, 'Year1': 2018}, {'Quarter': 1, 'Year1': 2019}, {'Quarter': 2, 'Year1': 2018}]. not sure why last value is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, is that new JSON data? what function call gives you that result? I am happy to help if you still need to get correct output

Comment: Hey, same json. I have created a separate function where i have updated the below line - next_4_quarters = [(i%4+1) for i in range(current_quarter, current_quarter+4)]. Not sure if this is the right approach to find next 4 quarters

Comment: yes that's the right approach, I think the last value is wrong because we need to use `if q <= current_quarter:` to indicate the current quarter integer will be for next year, not this year. I tried it with the same json data and should still get `290`